# How can I bubble events from the Repository through the Service up to the UI?

Tags: c#, events, repository, repository-pattern

I have a repository that uses components that report events.

I want to show the reported events in the front end.

This is the repository:

```
public interface IXmlRepository
{
    //irrelevant stuff removed
    event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;
}

public class XmlPanelRepository : IXmlRepository
{
    public XmlPanelRepository()
    {
        public event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;

        var panelCom = new PanelCom(); // this is a COM object that connects to a device

        // when something happens in the COM object it reports it.
        panelCom.Trace += panelCom_Trace; 

    // I want to bubble the trace events up to my UI.
        TraceEventHandler += TraceEventHandler_Tracing;
    }

    private void TraceEventHandler_Tracing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // what do I do here?
    }

    void panelCom_Trace(string message)
    {
        if (TraceEventHandler!= null) TraceEventHandler.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

My UI uses a Service to interface with the repository. The service is defined as:

```
public interface IXmlConfigurationService
{
    //irrelevant stuff removed

    event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;
}

public class XmlConfigurationService : IXmlConfigurationService
{
    public event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;

    public XmlConfigurationService(IXmlRepository configurationRepository)
    {
        _configurationRepository.TraceEventHandler += ConfigurationRepository_TraceEventHandler;
    }

    void ConfigurationRepository_TraceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this never gets hit.
        if (TraceEventHandler != null) TraceEventHandler.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

If I can get this working, I presume I can follow the same steps to get the UI displaying event reports.

How can I get the Service to report the events that are occurring in the repository?

Comment: Instead of bubbling events, send a trace listener type object (or one of your own making) from the UI down. In the `panelCom_Trace` handler, write to the listener. This seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: I agree with @Marc. You should not try to couple your layers together like this. However, if this is what you really, want, then I would suggest looking into a pub/sub pattern, or Observer pattern as dtryon suggests

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would need to fulfil your event.  This is akin to the Observable fulfilling all listening observers in the Observer Pattern.  But for events written like this:

```
public XmlPanelRepository()
    {
        public event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;

        var panelCom = new PanelCom(); // this is a COM object that connects to a device

        // when something happens in the COM object it reports it.
        panelCom.Trace += panelCom_Trace; 

    // I want to bubble the trace events up to my UI.
        TraceEventHandler += TraceEventHandler_Tracing;
    }

    private void TraceEventHandler_Tracing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TraceEventHandler != null)
        {
              TraceEventHandler(this, e);
        }

    }
```

However, perhaps you should name the event something other than `TraceEventHandler` because you are now exposing an event  (which usually is expressed in the past tense).

It is also worth noting that you can potentially change the event args as you bubble up (if you want to).  [EventHandler(TEventArgs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) can help with this.

Answer (score -1):

You're forgetting to use delegates...
Try something like this:

```
public interface IXmlRepository
{
   //irrelevant stuff removed
   event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;
}

public class XmlPanelRepository : IXmlRepository
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(string parameter1, string parameter2);

    public event EventHandler TraceEventHandler;

    public XmlPanelRepository()
    {
        var panelCom = new PanelCom(); // this is a COM object that connects to a device

        // when something happens in the COM object it reports it.
        panelCom.Trace += panelCom_Trace; 

    }

    void panelCom_Trace(string message)
    {
        if (EventHandler != null)
          EventHandler("Event was hit, here's the message:", message);
    }
}

public interface IXmlConfigurationService
{
    //irrelevant stuff removed
}

public class XmlConfigurationService : IXmlConfigurationService
{
    public XmlConfigurationService(IXmlRepository configurationRepository)
    {
        _configurationRepository.TraceEventHandler += ConfigurationRepository_EventHandler;
    }

    void ConfigurationRepository_EventHandler(string parameter1, string parameter2);)
    {
        // Do something with your parameters.
        Response.Write(parameter1 + parameter2);
    }
}
```

Comment: EventHandler is a delegate built in to .NET for events.

Comment: I quote the great Homer Simpson:  Dolt!